# mapreduce sample with select query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, select, mapreduce

I'm building a website using google app engine and python.

Currently i face with a problem when searching on large data. When i perform a query like:

```
student = Student.all().filter('__key__ =', student_obj).get().
```

( we have about 10 000 000 student records in datastore ).

I'm investigate to use some technique like task queue, mapreduce or full text search.

Any one who have experience in this field, please give me some example using mapreduce or task queue to due with those query.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what problem you're having here. What exactly are you trying to do? If you just want one object (which is what get() will give you) based on it's get, use db.get(the_key).

Comment: If you're just searching for one record by key, it's going to be extremely fast using the `get(key)` method described by Wooble above.

Comment: You say "currently I face a problem", but don't say what the problem is. Also, I second what @Wooble says: There's no point filtering by key, because a get does the same thing and is more efficient.